# Fiware Cygnus - Change service for only some entities with name mappings?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, ckan, fiware-cygnus

**Context :**
I have a machine with Orion Context Broker, Cygnus and Ckan. I have 3 entities (sensor1, sensor2, sensor3) and I use name mappings for these three entities to write in a single Ckan datastore named sensors. So far everything works.

**What I want :**
These 3 entities are in the fiware-service **default** and I want them to write in the fiware-service **paris** (the **paris** organization in Ckan)

**Question :**
How to make the name mapping change the **default** fiware-service of these 3 entities into **paris**, without changing it for all entities?

**What I tried :**
I tried this, the problem with this code is that all entities of the fiware-service **default** are moved to the fiware-service **paris**, not just my trhee entities.

```
{
   "serviceMappings": [
      {
         "originalService": "default",
         "newService": "paris",
         "servicePathMappings": [
            {
               "originalServicePath": "/",
               "entityMappings": [
                  {
                     "originalEntityId": "sensor1",
                     "originalEntityType": "device",
                     "newEntityId": "sensors",
                     "attributeMappings": []
                  },
                  {
                     "originalEntityId": "sensor2",
                     "originalEntityType": "device",
                     "newEntityId": "sensors",
                     "attributeMappings": []
                  },
                  {
                     "originalEntityId": "sensor3",
                     "originalEntityType": "device",
                     "newEntityId": "sensors",
                     "attributeMappings": []
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking to the examples in [the Cygnus documentation](https://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/master/cygnus-ngsi/installation_and_administration_guide/name_mappings/index.html) maybe you could try with a regular expression pattern:

> Last but not least, the original names support Java-based regular expressions.

For instance:

```
{
   "serviceMappings": [
      {
         "originalService": "default",
         "newService": "paris",
         "servicePathMappings": [
            {
               "originalServicePath": "/",
               "entityMappings": [
                  {
                     "originalEntityId": "sensor[1-3]",
                     "originalEntityType": "device",
                     "newEntityId": "sensors",
                     "attributeMappings": []
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm not fully sure it works for you but it may help...